# What accessories are used with this mysterious accessory port?

Tags: ps-vita

So, I got a PS Vita recently. As I was poking around trying to figure out how everything worked, I noticed this odd, unmarked port on the top of the system.

[image]

It's only labeled as "Accessories Terminal", but I can't find *any* indication as to *what* accessories are used here. I've checked the manual, but it doesn't shed any light on this mystery. Even the official [PS Vita Accessories](http://us.playstation.com/psvita/accessories/) page doesn't offer any information.

**What can I use with this port?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of now, nobody but Sony knows for sure. I believe it's for video output though, but Sony hasn't confirmed this.

[Speculation thread](http://psvitaforum.com/threads/accessory-port-guess-thread.6323/)

Some ideas include

- Extended battery pack
- Mini fight stick
- HDMI out
- Video out
- Connection to PS Vita/PS3
- Wireless audio connector

We'll just have to wait and see...

Comment: It is worth noting that the new Model PSV Slim model released last year in Japan and about to be released in the West no longer has this port. So in all probability we will never know what its intended use was.